# how to have a fixed coordinate system on opengl without using glViewPort

Tags: java, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0, scaling

I am currently learning Opengl ES for android.
I have read many tutorials that says that the coordinate system is from -1f -1f (bottom left corner) to 1f 1f top right corner.
That much I can figure out. But the problem I am currently experimenting is while I try to resize my triangles : the window seems to be resizing itself based on my extremum values. If this is the only triangle that I try to draw, on two different instances, the
0f, 0f,
0f, 0.01f,
0.01f, 0.01f
triangle is exactly the same as
0f, 0f
0f, 1f
1f, 1f
Honestly i'm a bit lost here. There is my code :
int vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID;

```
    int[] result = new int[1];
    _vertexSize = 2;
    _verticeCount = 3;
    _context = context;
    vertexShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, _context.getString(R.string.vertexShader));
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, _context.getString(R.string.fragmentShader));
    _programID = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderID, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, result,0);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderID, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, result,0);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(_programID, vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(_programID, fragmentShaderID);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(_programID);
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(_programID, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, result, 0);
    GLES20.glValidateProgram(_programID);

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1,result,0);
    vertexBufferID = result[0];
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    FloatBuffer coordBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(_vertexSize * _verticeCount);
    coordBuffer.put(coords);
    coordBuffer.position(0);
    Log.d("count", "" + SIZEOF_FLOAT * _verticeCount * _vertexSize);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SIZEOF_FLOAT * _verticeCount * _vertexSize, coordBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    coordBuffer.clear();
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,  true,2 * SIZEOF_FLOAT,0);
    Log.d("version", GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION));
```

i have also tried to replace
 `GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,  true,2 * SIZEOF_FLOAT,0);` by `GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,  false,2 * SIZEOF_FLOAT,0);`
thank you in advance for your help
P.-S : there is my shader `attribute highp vec2 inPosition; void main() { gl_Position = vec4(inPosition.x, inPosition.y,0.0,0.0)  ; }`

Answer (score 0):

found out the mistake i have made : My shader was wrong. the depth parameter of the gl_position was set to 0, so i guess it was going outside the screen no matter what. `gl_Position.xy = inPosition;` works just fine if `GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,  false,2 * SIZEOF_FLOAT,0);`. If the 4th parameter is true, it will rescale it.